# Detect ComboBox Change Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, dropdown

I have a sheet with a bunch of ComboBoxes(form control) and I want to detect when a user changes any one of them and write text in a cell. Using Worksheet_Change on the target cells doesn't work. I have tried a bunch of things that don't work. I'm not sure what needs to be in the private sub line or the if statement.

```
Private Sub DropDowns_DropButtonClick()
If ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Value > 1 Then
    Cells(13, 5).Font.Bold = True
    Cells(13, 5).Font.Color = vbRed
    Cells(13, 5).Value = "!!! Selections have been changed. !!!"
End If
End Sub
```

I have tried

```
ComboBox_AfterUpdate()
```

```
ComboBox_Change()
```

```
DropDowns_AfterUpdate()
```

```
DropsDowns_Change()
```

and anything else I could find. I've also tried a few different things in the if statement with no luck.

I appreciate any help.

Chris

Comment: Assign a macro to the combobox directly?

Comment: Life is easier in Forms. If you make a proper form then all those events will work.

Comment: I have 63 on one sheet and 207 on another, that's too many for individual macros for each box. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it by assigning a macro to the combobox (right click on the combobox>assign macro) as @BigBen mentioned in the comments section:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DropDown1_Change()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim dd As DropDown
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet") 'Name of the worksheet in which the combobox is located
    Set dd = sht.DropDowns("Drop Down 1") 'name of your combobox
    sht.Range("G1").Value = "The selected value is: " & dd.List(dd.Value) 'dd.value returns the index of the selected value
End Sub
```

You can use the same code for each one of your comboboxes. 
For demonstration purposes i have used the following set-up:

[image]

You can easily modify the code to best fit your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. I have 63 combo boxes on one sheet where I need this and 207 on another sheet, that's a bit too many macros to write, hence why I was looking for a way to look at them all at once. It's not critical for me to figure this out so if there's not an easy way I just wont worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading you correctly, you're comboboxes are in a userform. If I'm correct, simply open your userform in 'Visual Basic' and double click on the relavant combobox. This will open the code pane and create an empty Private Sub routine called 'Private Sub <*Combobox Name*> ()'.

Enter your code to place your data in the sheet (or whatever else you want) into the subroutine and Bob should be your uncle.

Apologies in advance if there's something I've missed.

RannochRob

Edit...

OK, my mistake, it's a form control.

My first comment is that it's easier to use an activex control if you can... however, with a form control, should (a) Use the cell link box in the 'Format Control' drop down ('Control' tab) to place the result in a cell... however, that result will not be the content of the box but an integer equal to the position of the selected entry on the list of entries in the combobox. You then need to (b) assign a macro to the combobox which will pick up the result and use it to get the required information from the range containing the list of entries. Like I say, much easier with an activex control...

RannochRob

Comment: Thanks. It's not a huge issue if I can't figure it out. Where I'm at now in the sheet's development it wouldn't be worth it to go back and change nearly 300 combo boxes to active x.